# How to get Twig.js for the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, twig, bower

I'm using Twig as my templating system on server side and also want to use it client side (to use the same templates).

I'm also using Bower and tried this command to get Twig.js:

```
bower install twig.js
```

But that didn't install all folders as seen here https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js. Then I tried to install other recent branches and commits but still 2 folders were missing at least (`bin` & `src`).

After that, I tried cloning the project using Git and it worked because it really got all listed files and folders.

But then when I include `twig.js` in my HTML file throws this error in the Chrome console log:

> twig.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

My best guess is that function "`require`" belongs to Node.js (right?) and there must be some kind of compilation to get Twig.js for the browser (right???).

So, I don't know what is next... How can I get the Twig.js for the browser? (Meanwhile I'm going to get Twig.js from a CDN).

Please help me.

Comment: You have to install `requirejs` to use `require("twig");`. Install that first and then run.

Comment: Thanks. Add your comment as an answer, so I can at least do it +1. Also, do you know what can I do to merge all files in src folder into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install RequireJS to use `require("twig");`. Install that first and then run.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which version of Twig.js you were using, since the question was posted almost 2 years ago, but probably something 0.9.x or higher. Since that version the maintainers did not commit any JS files compiled for web usage in the root of the project.

So yes, the JS files inside the `src/` folder are NodeJS files and you have *'to do something'* before you can use them in your browser. The library is using Webpack to build a browser compatible version.

You should run `npm install` in the root of the GitHub clone to set up the project and then run `npm run build` in order to build a web version. Check for `twig.js` in the root after that.

Using a CDN version is also a good option. But because the builds were left out since version 0.9.0 there is no newer version of Twig.js [on cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twig.js) than 0.8.9 while the library is currently on version 1.12.0

Answer (score 2):

Or run `npm install twig --save`, the compiled files are at:

- `node_modules/twig/twig.js` and
- `node_modules/twig/twig.min.js`

Comment: This is only true for versions below 0.9.0 as before 0.9 the maintainers did ship the compiled library inside the package. From version 0.9.0 an up these files are no longer there

Comment: @7ochem: I referred to the `node_modules/twig` folder, not to the `dist` folder. Just tried `npm install twig --save` again, version 1.12.0 was installed.

Comment: You're right, it is shipped in the published release. So it would be an option to use npm instead of bower to fetch Twig.js